# Sending more than one Web request

Tags: powershell

I have the following code as I am trying to send multiple requests to a Spectra tape library -

**

```
$results = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://spectra1/gf/login.xml?username=administrator&password=xxxxxxx&forceFrontPanel
$results = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://spectra1/gf/driveList.xml?action=list" -OutFile c:\temp\drivelist.txt
```

**

The first result is fine, it logs in but as soon as I send the second command it says:-

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<error>
  <message>You must go to login.xml and login before operating the library</message>
  <description>---- Error: No active session found.  
Visit login.xml to specify your username and password
</description>
</error>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Toy should save your session with login and use it for the second request. Like this:

```
$results = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://spectra1/gf/login.xml?username=administrator&password=xxxxxxx&forceFrontPanel" -SessionVariable spectra1Session
$results = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://spectra1/gf/driveList.xml?action=list" -WebSession $spectra1Session -OutFile c:\temp\drivelist.txt
```

`-SessionVariable spectra1Session` to save session in variable `$spectra1Session` and then `-WebSession $spectra1Session` to use saved session.

Comment: That worked a treat - Thank you so much, been fighting with this for sometime!

Comment: @cpj please [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) if it suits your situation.